# how to use IN operator in LINQ

Tags: asp.net, linq

I have the list of ProjectId like `14,15,18` and i want to search those items from my datatable using linq.

now i have created the query like

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> drProjList = from a in dtProj.AsEnumerable()
                                  where a.Field<int>("ProjectId")
                                        .ToString()
                                        .Contains(projFilter)
                                   select a;
```

but i am not getting the 0 elements.

can any body suggest me any other way like `IN` operator in linq.

thanks in advance

**EDIT**
projFilter is the pure string which have the 14,15,18,... project ids.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek its a string with the comma separated ProjectId's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about the AsEnumerable(), but I would have done it the other way round, something like this:

```
List<int> intProjFilter = new List<int>();

foreach(string filter in projFilter.Split(','))
       intProjFilter.Add(int.Parse(filter));

from a in dtProj 
where projFilter.Contains(a.ProjectID)
select a;
```

Let me know if this helps

Comment: But probably without the `.ToString()`.

Comment: I thought it was there because the projFilter was a list of strings. You might be right though

Comment: Hi @ExitMusic, this solution works for me but it is also returns the 1,4,8 with the 14,15,18 :(

Comment: You need to compare integar to integar I think. Remove the .ToString() and then create a list of integars to compare it to. I'll adapt my answer.

Answer (score 3):

String's "contains" isn't really an option here. You should convert projFilter into a proper list of integers first.

```
var projFilter2 = new HashSet<int>(projFilter.Split(',').Select(i => int.Parse(i)));
```

and only then check if it contains the desired number.

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> drProjList = 
    from a in dtProj.AsEnumerable()
    where projFilter2.Contains(a.Field<int>("ProjectId"))
    select a;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the project filter into collection of integers first.

```
var projectIds = projFilter.Split(',').Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToList();

var drProjList =
    from a in dtProj.AsEnumerable()
    where projectIds.Contains(a.ProjectId)
    select a;
```

Comment: oops fixed a typo. Suppose to be ToList() instead of ToString()

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> drProjList =
                       (
                          from a in dtProj.AsEnumerable()
                          where projFilter.Contains(a.Field<int>("ProjectId").ToString())
                          select a;
                       )
```

Or you can simply do this as well:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> drProjList=dtProj.AsEnumerable()
                                    .Where(a=>projFilter
                                          .Contains(a.Field<int>("ProjectId")
                                          .ToString()));
```

Comment: ,this are showing error that `the best overload method for string.Contains(string) has some invalid arguments.`

I think the `a.Field<int>("ProjectId")` needs `ToString()` ???

Comment: hi @Arion,thanks for quick reply.I am getting the same as the ExitMusic's query returns.How i will avoid those extra 1,4,8 ProjectIds ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know c# well so i am trying to give answer in vb.net hope that will help you.

```
    Dim dtProj As DataTable
    dtProj = FillProjectList()

    Dim projIdFilter() As Integer = {14, 15, 16}

    Dim drRow = From p In dtProj.AsEnumerable _ 
        Where projIdFilter.Contains(p.Field(Of Integer)("ProjectId")) _
        Select p
```

Thank you...